# Must enter Hostname for new dedicated server - Limitations?

Tags: hostname

I am planning to purchase a dedicated server. However, there is a section where I must enter a "HOSTNAME". They describe it as the following:

```
Enter Hostname (my.server.com)
```

My questions are now:

1. What is a 'normal' hostname? is it "server1" or "server1.domain.com"?
2. Do I need a hostname?
3. Can I enter anything I want, e.g. "kangaroo" as hostname?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hostnames - What are they all about?](http://serverfault.com/questions/228102/hostnames-what-are-they-all-about)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a fully qualified domain name (like server1.domain.com as opposed to just server1), under a domain that you have registered and own. It's not an absolute necessity for the local server to know what its name is, but odd problems can arise with certain applications. Just play it safe.

For example, if you have registered "kangarooserver.com," you can call the server "whatever.kangarooserver.com". Obviously you can put anything in place of "whatever" in the example above.

Comment: Thanks! This is 100% sure the answer I was looking for. SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

Many hoster set a TLD to your Server. When you write "server1.xxxseg.de" they register the domain "xxxseg.de" and put the subdomain "server1" to your mashine. Its a bit different from hoster to hoster.

But i think here you need a qualified TLD (top level domain). If its a really good hoster you can call them or write an email and ask, if you need the domain or if they set only the ip on the server.

But then you need your own domain and set this to your public ip address.

Comment: A TLD is .com, .net, .org, etc. `xxxseg.de` is not a TLD, .de is.

Answer (score 0):

An FQDN (as above explained: fully qualified domain name)

Is (especially in linux systems) used by mail and web servers to identify under what name the program will be reached either inside the network on from the internet...
But most of these programs also allow you to enter a different name

I have most of my hostnames set to names like virt-deb-3 (Virtual server - Debian - 192.168.1.103)
But that server is reached by mail..org

So if you want to do it right it you should enter an FQDN
for external: ..
for internal: ..local

Smartest thing to do here is just call the hosting company itself and ask ;>